# CONDITIONAL statement with sequential values in SAS

Tags: sas

2I am writing an IF statement to filter out some values which are sequential. Is there a way to write an IF statement to bring out the sequential values

```
data H; 
input HH $; 
cards; 
Y1
Y2
Y3
Y4
Y5
; run; 


data t; 
set H; 
if hh in ('Y2' -'Y4');
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that `<` and `>` work with character variables and sort order:

```
data t; 
set H; 
if 'Y2' <= hh <= 'Y4';
run;
```

However, `Y22` would also be sorted between `Y2` and `Y4`.

```
data H; 
input HH $; 
cards; 
Y1
Y2
Y3
Y4
Y5
Y22
; run; 


data t; 
set H; 
if 'Y2' <= hh <= 'Y4';
run;
```

So you would need to add additional logic in that case.

Comment: Precede the Y1-9's with a zero, Y01, Y02, Y03, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Scan` function to extract the number part then filer the numbers you want:

`if  scan(hh,1,'Y') >= 1 & scan(hh,1,'Y') <=4;`

New Datastep:

```
data t; 
set H; 
if  scan(hh,1,'Y') >= 1 & scan(hh,1,'Y') <=4;
run;
```